# Can our SO profile link to a public published CV, if we have one?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, cv

I don't want to use my website field, since I'm working on a website that I'll be putting there. And it should be somewhere other than the "About Me" field. Especially since one of the 6th hit (5th if you don't count the image results) [for "Thomas Owens" on Google](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=%22Thomas+Owens%22&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&fp=8ec9ea851cee2c5b) is my SO Profile! If you add [+software](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=%22Thomas+Owens%22+%2Bsoftware&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&fp=8ec9ea851cee2c5b), I move to 2 (1 if you count the LinkedIn search page) and if you add [+software engineering](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=%22Thomas+Owens%22+%2Bsoftware+engineering&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&fp=8ec9ea851cee2c5b), I'm 1!

Answer (score 4):

I use my [profile field](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker) as follows:

> I'm a Software Developer. I'm also a
>   PC. But I could be a Mac. I talk about
>   software, programming, and usability
>   on my [**blog**](http://blog.yapb.net)
>
> ---
>
> **What I'm Good at**:
>
> - Communicating
> - Creating **sensible** software solutions
> - Self-aggrandizing sentences (like these).
>
> Catch me on:
>    - **[twitter](http://twitter.com/gortok)**
>    - **Linked In**
>
> Want to see what I've
>   done?
>
> - Check my [**CV**](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/george-stocker) or
>     my [**Portfolio**](http://blog.yapb.net/page/My-Portfolio.aspx)

---

I think of the `About Me` field much like I do the `Personal Statement` in a CV, except that it's a general thing; so that's why I include links to it there.

> **Note**: The `About Me` field that I'm currently dealing with:  If you have too much, it adds a scrollbar; which makes people less likely to look at your content. If you've got any suggestions as to how I can get rid of the scrollbar on mine, I'm all ears. Right now I've got HTML crammed in there and if I could get rid of a few characters I'd be back to no scroll-bar.

Comment: You really only need to drop one line... Either cram the "catch me on" or "want to see what i've done" lists onto a single line and you're there.

Comment: What's funny about that is I went ahead and did that right before you made this comment. Great minds think alike.

Comment: Ah, looks much nicer now :-)

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with the "About me" field? It's freeform text, you can put as many links as you like in there; why not **use it** rather than cluttering up the rest of the page? It's not like you have a [particularly long bio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52443)...