# Add a Twitter field to user profiles

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, twitter, social-networking

Has anyone considered the potential of having a Twitter ID field in the profile (or fields for other similar microblogging/social networking services) so that those who want to can advertise their other profiles, allowing people to network with people in their field?

The particular value of this, I feel, is more in Stack Exchange sites where the sites are often much more specialised and you are participating in a small community where it's useful to keep tabs on who's doing what.

Comment: Are you trying to keep your About Me section nice and clean? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27575/moar-boxes-to-add-spammy-links

Comment: [tag:status-completed]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249951/388442

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add your twitter link to your profile's **Website** field or in your about me secion:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/username">my twitter</a>
```

I think that would be just as effective.