# Twitter as user information

Tags: support, user-accounts, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a Twitter field to user profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29547/add-a-twitter-field-to-user-profiles)

Can user information on accounts be extended?

I am thinking it would be useful to include a Twitter link not only in general information, but as its own field?

I often find new friends and fellow geeks that I want to include on Twitter IM or similar, but I can't always find the relevant information to identify the person (not including being able to do so as a moderator, as that would count as abuse).

Comment: @Toni: It should be OK here.. each stackexchange site's meta is monitored as well.